# Why it doesn't go to end sometimes

Tags: python

The code reads urls from file and push it to queue assigned to thread and do third party web api call in order to get result that goes to the global list. 
When I execute this program sometime it will go to the end and finishes process(printing done) sometime it is stuck and hold the process never finishes.

It seems like if there is an exception("We failed to reach a server") it holds the process and never finishes. I believe that it is thread problem.

Any body can figure it out what is the issue please. Thank you in advance

Here is the code

```
import threading
import Queue
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
import sys
import httplib, urllib, time, random, os
import json
from urlparse import urlparse
import time

#Number of threads
n_thread = 50
#Create queue
queue = Queue.Queue()
domainBlacklistDomain=[]
urlList=[]

def checkBlackList(domain,line):

        testUrl = 'https://test.net'
        apiToken = 'aaaaa'
        secretKey = 'bbbb'
        signature_data = 'GET\n/v1/blacklist/lookup\nurl='+domain+'\n\n\n'
        digest = hmac.new(secretKey, signature_data, hashlib.sha1).digest()
        digest_base64 = base64.encodestring(digest)
        req = urllib2.Request('https://test.net/v1/blacklist/lookup?url='+domain)
        req.add_header('Authorization', 'Test' + apiToken + ':' + digest_base64)
        req.add_header('Connection', 'Keep-Alive')
        try:
                page = urlopen(req)
                length = str(page.info())
                if length.find("Content-Length: 0") != -1:
                        url=str(line.strip())
                        urlList.append(url)


                else:
                        json_data=json.load(page)
                        domainBlacklistDomain.append(json_data['url'])

                        if int(json_data['score']) >10:

                                print json_data['url']

        except HTTPError, e:
                 print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'

        except URLError, e:
                print 'We failed to reach a server.'






  class ThreadClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    #Assign thread working with queue
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
        #Get from queue job
            host = self.queue.get()
            parsed_uri = urlparse(host)
            domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
            if "\n" in domain:
                domain=domain.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
                if domain not in domainBlacklistDomain:
                        checkBlackList(domain,host):

            else:
                if domain not in domainBlacklistDomain:
                        checkBlackList(domain,host):

        #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

#Create number process
for i in range(n_thread):
    t = ThreadClass(queue)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    #Start thread
    t.start()

#Read file line by line
hostfile = open("result_url.txt","r")
for line in hostfile:
    #Put line to queue
    queue.put(line)
#wait on the queue until everything has been processed
queue.join()

fo=open("final_result.txt","w+b")
for item in urlList:
        fo.write("%s\n" %item)

print "done??"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without reading your code in detail, the issue is almost certainly to do with trying to establish a connection to a non-responsive IP address. The timeouts on these connections can be lengthy.

Try using the `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` function to establish a global socket timeout.